# Exercise and proof given in a Number Theory textbook

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $(\forall m\in\mathbb N)(\exists$ $x,y \in \mathbb N)$, s.t. $x-y \geq m$ and $\sigma(x^2)=\sigma(y^2)$
>   $\sigma(x):=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^kd_i,\;d_i\mid x,\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,k\},\;k\le x$

Proof (in text book):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n > m$ and $(n,10)=1$ . For $x=5n$, $y=4n$, we have $x-y=n>m$ and $\sigma(x^2)=\sigma(y^2)=31 \sigma(n^2)$

I don't think this is true. For example, let $n=17$, $m=12$

Comment: How is $\sigma(x)$ defined?

Comment: The sum of the divisors. I tried to paste a picture of the textbook but I don't think I was allowed

Comment: Ok, you can add this as text.

Comment: You don't think *what* is right?  As of now you have posted nothing.

Comment: @Studentinmy50s Welcome to Math SE. Please update your question text to indicate what relationship there is between $m$ and $n$ with $x^2$ and $y^2$.

Comment: The theorem doesn't say it is true for *all* $x,y$.  It says it is true for *some* $x,y$.  If $m=12$ you just need to find *some* $x$ and $y$ where $x-y \ge 12$ and $\sigma(x^2)= \sigma(y^2)$.  Are you saying you can *never* find such an $x$?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, $n$ is not relatively prime to 10 as both share the divisor 2. So, this is not a counterexample to the proof.

EDIT: You have changed the values of n and m now. Still, the proof/theorem works.

Now we have $x = 5*17$, y = $4*17$, and $x-y = 17 > m$.

$\sigma((4*17)^2) = \sigma(16)*\sigma(17^2)= 31*\sigma(17^2) = \sigma(25)*\sigma(17^2)$

Thus these values are equal and the condition is satisfied.

Further, keep in mind that from the statement of the theorem it is only required that some $x$ and $y$ satisfies the question and does not need to be true for all.

Comment: Sorry I meant n=17, m=12, I just edited. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now

Answer (score 1):

General framework. It's interesting to study natural numbers $\ s<t\ $ such that $\ \sigma(s)=\sigma(t).\ $ In particular, it's a tough challenge to find natural numbers $\ a<b\ $ such that $\ \sigma(a^2)=\sigma(b^2).\ $ Indeed, this last equation is the difficult part of the given exercise.

Once you have such $\ a<b\ $ then routine considerations solve the problem. Namely, you can always find a prime number $\ p\ $ such that it divides neither $\ a\ $ nor $\ b. $ Every prime $\ p>b\ $ would do. Then we would have:

$$ \sigma(a^2\cdot p^2)\ =\ \sigma(b^2\cdot p^2) $$

In particular, $\ b^2\cdot p^2 - a^2\cdot p^2\ $ can be arbitrarily large
-- just take appropriately huge prime $p$.

Thus, the main challenge is finding solutions for
$\ \sigma(a^2)=\sigma(b^2)\ $ (where $a\ne b$). The textbook mentioned
in OP's question provided

$$ \sigma(4^2)\ =\ \sigma(5^2)\ =\ 31 $$

When you play with the perfect and multi-perfect numbers (I call them
*baroque numbers*) then you run into more examples.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question, where do I learn to type math equations for this kind of forums?

Comment: The in-line formulas you write between dollar signs, and the stand-alone formulas you write between double dollar signs. You need to use the so-called mathematics mode of TeX (or LaTeX or their variations) to do so. You may pretend to edit an existing question or answer on this forum. This will give you the view of the original source code of the text. Don't type there anything. When you're done with looking then discard the editing.